# How do I prevent logging an encrypted airflow variable?

Tags: etl, airflow

I've set up an airflow which has an encrypted variable declared. I'm using [BigQueryOperator](https://github.com/apache/incubator-airflow/blob/master/airflow/contrib/operators/bigquery_operator.py). I use the encrypted variable in the SQL that is fed to the class. But the airflow logs the SQL after decrypting the variable. How can I prevent that from happening?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no built-in way to achieve this.

A possible work-around is removing `self.log.info('Executing: %s', self.sql)` line in `BigQueryOperator` or creating a new Operator inheriting `BigQueryOperator` like below:

```py
class CustomBQOperator(BigQueryOperator):
    @apply_defaults
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CustomBQOperator).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def execute(self, context):
        if self.bq_cursor is None:

            hook = BigQueryHook(
                bigquery_conn_id=self.bigquery_conn_id,
                use_legacy_sql=self.use_legacy_sql,
                delegate_to=self.delegate_to)
            conn = hook.get_conn()
            self.bq_cursor = conn.cursor()
        self.bq_cursor.run_query(
            self.sql,
            destination_dataset_table=self.destination_dataset_table,
            write_disposition=self.write_disposition,
            allow_large_results=self.allow_large_results,
            flatten_results=self.flatten_results,
            udf_config=self.udf_config,
            maximum_billing_tier=self.maximum_billing_tier,
            maximum_bytes_billed=self.maximum_bytes_billed,
            create_disposition=self.create_disposition,
            query_params=self.query_params,
            labels=self.labels,
            schema_update_options=self.schema_update_options,
            priority=self.priority,
            time_partitioning=self.time_partitioning,
            api_resource_configs=self.api_resource_configs,
            cluster_fields=self.cluster_fields,
        )
```

And then using this `CustomBQOperator` instead of `BigQueryOperator`